# How to Prevent Hibernate from Initializing Collections in Empty Composites?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm working with Hibernate and JPA's @Embeddable annotation to create composite attributes for my entities (I'm using composites as value objects). I've noticed some inconsistent behavior when these embeddables contain a Collection attribute. Specifically, the way Hibernate initializes these composites varies based on the presence of collection attributes.

**Context:**

**Null Composite Handling:** If all attributes within a composite (@Embeddable) object are null, Hibernate considers the entire composite as null. This is logical and expected.

**Null Collection Handling:** If an attribute of type Collection is null when Hibernate loads data from the database, it sets this attribute to an empty collection. This makes sense since having null collections is generally considered bad practice.

**The Issue:**

The above behaviors together create an inconsistent initialization pattern:

When I retrieve an @Embeddable object from the database that was originally saved with only null attributes, and one of those attributes is a Collection, Hibernate initializes the composite. This happens because the collection attribute is set to empty, thereby making the composite non-null.

Example:
To clarify, for some embedded properties, I end up having to do complex checks like:

```
if (entity.getAttribute() != null && 
    entity.getAttribute().getFoo() != null && 
    !entity.getAttribute().getCollection().isEmpty()) {
  //...
}
```

**Workaround:**

I thought about introducing an isValid() method in all my @Embeddable classes. With this, I would always check:

```
if (entity.getAttribute() != null && entity.getAttribute().isValid()) {
  //...
}
```

However, this approach feels like a hack and clutters the domain model with code that's solely there to mitigate an ORM behavior.

**Question:**

Is there a way to configure Hibernate to avoid initializing the collections within @Embeddable objects that have all other attributes set to null? I want to preserve the nullability of the entire composite object in such cases.